# determining windows restored size

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to generate a bitmap containing what would be displayed if a window were to be restored to the desktop.  GetWindowRect returns it's minimized size, GetWindowplacement returns where it would go. But I can't find a api that tells me how big it would be.

How do I determine how big the window would be if restored?

Comment: Doesn't `WINDOWPLACEMENT::rcNormalPosition` work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetWindowPlacement` is indeed what you want. Use the `rcNormalPosition` which is a `RECT` containing the coordinates of the normalised position. Or, if `WPF_RESTORETOMAXIMIZED` is in the window placement `flags` then use the work area of the monitor with which the window is associated.

Having said that, `GetWindowPlacement` can sometimes return misleading information in `rcNormalPosition` on Windows 7.  I've come across this when you use the half screen Aero snap  feature. After you do that, and if the window is still normalised when you ask the question, you will find that `GetWindowPlacement` returns in `rcNormalPosition` a `RECT` that does not match the Aero snap position. Deal with that by simply using `GetWindowRect` if the window is normalised.

Answer (score 4):

`GetWindowPlacement` tells you exactly how big the window would be. The `rcNormalPosition` field is a `RECT` giving you the dimensions. The get the height and width, subtract top from bottom, left from right.

Note MSDN's comment about the rectangle being in *workspace coordinates*, not screen coordinates:

> Workspace coordinates differ from screen coordinates in that they take the locations and sizes of application toolbars (including the taskbar) into account. Workspace coordinate (0,0) is the upper-left corner of the workspace area, the area of the screen not being used by application toolbars.